# Sierra Terminal Automatically Escapes Pasted URLs

Tags: terminal, macos

1. Copy a URL that has some query string into clipboard like: `https://www.google.com/webhp?q=macos`
2. Paste the URL in Terminal (CMD+v), the Terminal automatically escapes `?` and `=` and changes the text to `https://www.google.com/webhp\?q\=macos`.

How can I turn this automatic escaping off?

[Edit]: a screen capture of the problem:

[image: Screen capture showing the problem]

Comment: I have copied and pasted `https://www.google.com/webhp?q=macos` from your question into Terminal under macOS 10.12.2 and cannot reproduce the stated behavior. (Even when attempting to execute the pasted URL as if it were a command.) The URL I copied is exactly what was copied and it **did not** automatically escape the `?` or `=` characters. That said, anytime I have a need to paste a URL into Terminal it's typically an argument of a _command_, e.g. `wget`, `curl`, etc., and I always place it within single quotes so it's treated as a literal string to the shell and isn't erroneously escaped.

Comment: Terminal automatically escapes the URLs, even when I try to paste them between quotes. It happens the moment I press CMD+v.

Comment: Even doing as you show in your updated question I cannot reproduce the issue in the macOS 10.12.2 Terminal.app that by default uses the `bash` shell. From the appearance of the .gif file you're not use the default shell and while it shows zsh in the image nonetheless you should have stated your not using the default shell! Anyway, using the zsh shell I still cannot reproduce the stated behavior as it still pastes exactly as I copied it, that being: `https://www.google.com/webhp?q=macos` If you have modified the zsh shell as well, you'll need to state what you've done too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is either a bug in `zsh` or a configuration issue for **bracketed-paste-magic** or **url-quote-magic**

You could use a different shell or remove / add configuration for `zsh` to remedy this feature/bug:

- [How to disable URL escape in zsh](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25614613/475228)